# Safety for using void *pointer to object

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

**Long story:**

Currently, I am assigned to work with a legacy C project that need to be update to integrate with new camera device. The API from device's manufacturer is pretty simple, all I need is include their headers and libs into my class to work with the device, example here is a sample snippet of code:

*MyClass.h*

```
#include <XFactory.h>
...
public:
XFactory::device    myDevice;
XFactory::xSmartPtr myPtr;
```

To integrate with the device:

*MyClass.cpp*

```
#include "MyClass.h"
...
myDevice.GetInfo();
myPtr.GetFrame();
..ect.
```

But life always gives you lemon. Whenever I `#include MyClass.h` to the main project. The complier throw error similar like this:

```
...
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: note: template<class  _Tp> const _Tp& std::min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
...
```

Did some research, and I assume that `#include <XFactory.h>` calls some C++ header which is conflicted with macro defined in some classes in my project(like min/max...). I can't fix those codes, which is not mine, so here is my ugly workaround for my class:

**Short story:**

*MyClass.h*

```
typedef void* DeviceHandle_t;
typedef void* FrameHandle_t;

public:
DeviceHandle_t myDevice;
FrameHandle_t myPtr;
```

*MyClass.cpp*

```
#include <XFactory.h> //to avoid main project include this header
MyClass::MyClass(){
   myDevice = new XFactory::device();
   myPtr = new XFactory::xSmartPtr();
}

MyClass::~MyClass(){
   if (myDevice != NULL){
      delete (XFactory::device*)myDevice; //this will call class's destructor, won't it?
      myDevice = NULL;
   }

   if (myDevice != NULL){
      delete (XFactory::xSmartPtr*)myPtr ; //this will call class's destructor, won't it?
      myPtr = NULL;
   }       
}
```

To integrate with the device:

```
((XFactory::device*)myDevice)->GetInfo();
((XFactory::xSmartPtr*)myPtr)->GetFrame();
```

Yes, I can't use smart pointer, because my project is on C99, and I barely have experience in working with pointers in C/C++, is my workaround safety ? and is there any other workaround for not using raw pointer?

Comment: Your code appears to be C++, and is not legal C. Also your variable definitions should be in a .cpp, not a header file. Also shouldn't myDevice and myPtr be member variables rather than global?

Comment: What particular aspects of safety are you concerned about? Simply leaking memory or the surrender of type safety by using void pointers? As for whether the destructors are called, can you not test that yourself?

Comment: Maybe you're using `<windows.h>` and have forgotten to define `NOMINMAX`. Always do that.

Comment: I prefer my class to be written in C++, while most of the code written on the main project is heavily in C. And the people who wrote that was defined some macro like min/max in main project header... for their convenient, and when I use C++ header like <iostream> the compiler will show error I mentioned before. 
And yes, make variables become member variable makes life easiler. Just wonder, if I should use void* pointer like this to access those object outside the class?

Answer (score 0):

This indeed isn't safe, nor needed.

The proper solution is just forward declarations:

*MyClass.h*

```
class DeviceHandle;
class FrameHandle;

public:
DeviceHandle* myDevice;
FrameHandle* myPtr;
```

It doesn't make sense to say your project is on C99; `public:` is the giveaway that you're on C++. And that means you can use smart pointers, e.g. `boost::shared_ptr`. Every version of C++ supports them, but no version of C (not even C11) has them.